Make A- and M- keybindings work properly within neovim and wezterm
I know that by default it's not possible to have proper Alt-keybindings in nvim since the terminal emulator (I think it's not only wezterm that does this) only sends \e<key> combos down the tty since Alt mappings are not int the ASCII set... I understand that. But since it has a lot of downsides to not being able to map Esc and Alt seperately, I thought I might give this another shot. Given my understanding of the  situation (correct me if I'm wrong):
wezterm ---> tty ---> nvim

Whereas nvim is listening to some keycombo that it interprets as Alt+... (sidequestion: what exact sequence is nvim listening for here?)
shouldn't it be possible to

Instruct wezterm to map the Alt key to a tty-conforming character sequence
Send that sequence down the tty
Translate it back on the other end
Have neovim interpret it as Alt (<A-..> and <M-..> keybindings work by default)

I heard that the terminfo database can be used to do tricks like this. But I'm not familiar with it. how would I go about doing that?
